# How do I change axes scale?

Tags: plotting, scaling

I am plotting

```
f[x_] := 2*x + 1
Plot[f[x], {x, -10, 10}]
```

BUT I want to scale my axes differently. By default it is 1:2 , meaning 1 unit on $y$ axis is equal to 2 units on $x$ axis. I want to manually specify it. I tried to use `AspectRatio`, but this only changes my graph, and not the axes... What can I do?

Comment: It is not clear to me what your result should actually look like.  Do you want to essentially *relabel* the axis or actually change the proportion of the plot?  How you wish your scaling factor to interact with `AspectRatio`?

Comment: I want to change the proportion of the plot. I want to have the same unit on both axes. For example: If my x axis is in m (meters) and y also in m (meters) I would like to see how the graph looks like if I change the y to km (kilometers) while x stays in m (meters). I hope you understand me now.

Comment: I posted an answer.  Please review it and use it as a reference for additional clarification if necessary.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I could interpret this question a couple of different ways.  One is that you would like to scale the proportion of your plot.  One can use [`ScalingFunctions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ScalingFunctions.html) (though undocumented for `Plot`) to specify the intended relationship, which will be correctly handled with `AspectRatio -> Automatic`.  For example:

```
Table[
 Plot[3 Sin[2 x], {x, 0, 7}, ScalingFunctions -> {scale, Identity}, 
  AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All],
 {scale, {{2 # &, #/2 &}, Identity, {#/2 &, 2 # &}}}
] // GraphicsRow
```

[image]

Note that unlike setting the proportion using a specific value for `AspectRatio` I did not have to manually calculate this value; it was computed automatically.

Another interpretation is that you wish to relabel one of the plot axes, easily done with a coefficient in the right place:

```
GraphicsRow[{
  Plot[3 Sin[2 x], {x, 0, 7}],
  Plot[(3 Sin[2 x])/2, {x, 0, 7}],
  Plot[3 Sin[2 (x/2)], {x, 0, 14}]
}]
```

[image]

These two behaviors may be combined to produce most any scaling you desire.

Comment: Nice stuff, but I noticed you use `ScalingFunctions -> {scale, Identity}`. Simpler would be `ScalingFunctions -> scale`, or is there something I'm missing?. +1.

Comment: @RunnyKine The output is not the same; try it. (At least in v10.0.1)

Comment: You're right, so what is the difference? I noticed using it the way I specified gave results identical  to, say e.g. `ListLogPlot` when I use `{#&, Log@# &}` as the scaling.

Comment: @RunnyKine There are two issues here I think.  First is that there are different forms for the option value: "{f,f^-1}  use the scaling function f and its inverse f^-1" and "{s1, s2, ...} use several scaling functions si for direction i" so a direct substitution of `ScalingFunctions -> scale` in my code above will not work.  The second issue is that even if I modify my `Table` iterator values to work with the shorter syntax the output *still* is not the same; the tick marks are different.  I do not know why; I just assumed the "{f,f^-1}" format was needed internally.  (continued)

Comment: Notice how the tick marks produced by this vary undesirably from that shown in the first image in my answer above: `Table[Plot[3 Sin[2 x], {x, 0, 7}, ScalingFunctions -> scale, AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All], {scale, {#/2 &, # &, 2 # &}}] // GraphicsRow`

Comment: Quick question:
Why doesn't this work??
`ParametricPlot[
 R*{Sin[\[Phi]], -Cos[\[Phi]]}, {\[Phi], -\[Phi]0, \[Phi]0}, 
 ScalingFunctions -> {Identity, Identity}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
 PlotRange -> All]`

Comment: @skrat What do you mean by "doesn't work?"  With (arbitrarily) `R = 0.3;
\[Phi]0 = 1.5;` I get a plot; presumably you do too but something is not as you expected.  What is that something?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Hi, I need only one plot. How can I plot only the graph in the middle?

Comment: @AmbicaGovind Try this `{scale, {Identity}}`